# How to change color scheme using css only?

Tags: html, css

Hey can any one tell me that is there any way to change the color scheme within the website. Wait I will explain it clearly with some code.

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {}
```

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {}
```

Is there any way that by using HTML button can we change the color scheme light to dark.

I have searched the whole internet and didn't find a right answer. Although I am new to Css. So please solve my query.

Comment: The prefers-color-scheme CSS media feature is used to detect if the user has requested a light or dark color theme. You can not switch that specific preference, but you can ignore this preference and just make a button that switches between CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSS variables you can change them with JavaScript like so:

```js
var usesDarkTheme = false;

function changeColorTheme() {
  const body = document.body;
  if (usesDarkTheme) {
    body.style.setProperty('--main-color', 'white');
    usesDarkTheme = false;
  } else {
    body.style.setProperty('--main-color', 'black');
    usesDarkTheme = true;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  --main-color: white;
}

.content {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"> </div>

<button onclick="changeColorTheme()">Change Color Theme</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it automatically change or manually, like this:

```js
  document.getElementById("theme").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const meta = document.querySelector('meta[name="color-scheme"]');
    if (meta.content === "light") {
      meta.content = "dark";
      document.body.classList.remove("light-mode");
      document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    } else {
      meta.content = "light";
      document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
      document.body.classList.add("light-mode");
    }
  });
```

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        --color-primary: #0a0a0a;
        --color-secondary: #339eff;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    :root {
        --color-primary: #ffffff;
        --color-secondary: #ff7e33;
    }
}

.light-mode {
    --color-primary: #ffffff;
    --color-secondary: #ff7e33;
}

.dark-mode {
    --color-primary: #0a0a0a;
    --color-secondary: #339eff;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light" />
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" />
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" />
  </head>
  <body>
    This is a test

    <button id="theme">Change theme</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can change it to your needs, but this is according to [web.dev](https://web.dev/color-scheme/). Remember to set the prefers-color-scheme colors, and then change it automatically or by a manual toggle, using the .light-mode and .dark-mode classes.

Answer (score 0):

> How to change color scheme using css only?

There are multiple ways to update a **color scheme** on a web page.

If you don't intend to write your own elaborately customised themes, there is a way to update a color scheme (between *Operating System Light Color Scheme* and *Operating System Dark Color Scheme*) **via CSS** and at **page level** (ie. not at Browser or Operating System level).

To achieve this, you can take advantage of the CSS declaration:

```
:root {
  color-scheme: normal;
}
```

---

### A couple of notes before we continue:

1. Most importantly, note that `color-scheme` has a very specific application here - pertaining to **Interactive Form Elements** - so updating `color-scheme` will affect the appearance of *only a limited subset of non-styled HTML elements* including `<input type="text">`, `<textarea>` etc. and also `:root`
2. Also note that colors produced by `color-scheme: light` and `color-scheme: dark` cannot be customised. They explicitly refer to the *Light Color Scheme* and *Dark Color Scheme* of whatever Operating System you're using
3. Thirdly, note that this approach *isn't strictly* **css-only** because you will still need JavaScript to update the CSS property on `:root`:

   *e.g.* `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('color-scheme', 'dark');`
4. Fourthly, note that although we're using JavaScript to update CSS here and not HTML, `:root {color-scheme: dark;}` *is* the CSS equivalent of the HTML metatag `<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark" />`

---

**Working Example:**

*Try the **radio buttons** below:*

```js
const radioButtons = document.querySelector('.radio-buttons');
const textboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.textbox');

const toggleMode = (e) => {
  
  let colorScheme = e.target.dataset.mode;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('color-scheme', colorScheme);
  textboxes.forEach((textbox, i) => {
  
    if ((i === 1) || (i === 3)) {
      textbox.value = 'Page Color Scheme\n(' + colorScheme + ')';
    }
  });
}

radioButtons.addEventListener('change', toggleMode);
```

```css
:root {
  color-scheme: normal;
}

fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: none;
}

.radio-buttons {
  width: 110px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.textbox {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  width: 158px;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
}

.textbox:nth-of-type(odd) {
  clear: left;
}

.normal-scheme {
  color-scheme: normal;
}

.light-theme {
  color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
  background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}

.dark-theme {
  color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  background-color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .normal-theme {
    color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    background-color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  .normal-theme {
    color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>

<fieldset class="radio-buttons">
<label><input type="radio" name="mode" data-mode="normal" checked /> OS Default</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="mode" data-mode="light" /> Light Mode</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="mode" data-mode="dark" /> Dark Mode</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<textarea class="textbox light-theme">
CSS Hardcoded
(light theme)
</textarea>

<textarea class="textbox">
Page Color Scheme
(normal)
</textarea>

<textarea class="textbox dark-theme">
CSS Hardcoded
(dark theme)
</textarea>

<textarea class="textbox">
Page Color Scheme
(normal)
</textarea>

<textarea class="textbox normal-theme">
CSS @media Query
(refers to OS Setting)
</textarea>

<textarea class="textbox normal-scheme">
Browser Color Scheme
(browser default)
</textarea>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

### A few more notes:

- The dark and light themes I've hardcoded into the CSS above are (deliberately) slightly darker than the System-native dark and light themes. This is so that whenever styles update above, you can see whether the new styles have come from the *CSS Stylesheet* or from the *Operating System*
- You'll see that the radio buttons alone are sufficient to change the *Page Color Scheme* from `normal` to `light` to `dark` - and that when they do, the styling comes from the *Operating System*
- If you *then* go into your browser tools and *simulate* OS Dark Mode, you'll see the bottom left `<textbox>` update from `Light` to `Dark` - when it does, you'll see the styling comes from the styles declared in the `prefers-color-scheme` `@mediaQuery` in the *CSS Stylesheet*

**In Summary:** you can toggle the presentation of unstyled **Interactive Form Elements** between *Operating System Light Color Scheme* and *Operating System Dark Color Scheme* at page level via CSS and a very small amount of JavaScript. But this isn't (at all) the same as writing your own *Light Theme* and *Dark Theme* and toggling between them.

Comment: Many statements in this answer do not correspond to the actual standard, so be aware.  For example, this answer states that `color-scheme` is setting colors on some interactive elements: this is completely misleading.  `color-scheme` is an attribute that specifies whether an element supports the specified theme and has nothing to do with the colors themselves, e.g. if you specify `color-scheme: light` it will instruct the browser that the element only supports the light scheme, but not the dark one.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand you completely but if you want to change primary color just use javascript and add onclick in html button